# AWK command for combining two files with separate ':' like output

Tags: linux, awk, command

Consider:

File 1

```
1
2
3
```

File 2

```
23
45
27
67
867
```

Output

```
1:23
1:45
1:27
1:67
1:867
2:23
2:45
2:27
2:67
2:867
3:23
3:45
3:27
3:67
3:867
```

How can I command this output using AWK using delimiter ':' from file 1 and file 2 like output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to solve your problem; this may suit your use-case:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[++n]=$0; next} {for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {print $0 ":" a[i]}}' file2 file1
1:23
1:45
1:27
1:67
1:867
2:23
2:45
2:27
2:67
2:867
3:23
3:45
3:27
3:67
3:867
```

With nicer formatting and comments

```
awk '
NR==FNR{            # For the first file
       a[++n]=$0    # Load values into an array
       next         # Then skip to the next line/file
}

{
       for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {    # For all the items in the array
              print $0 ":" a[i]  # Print the value from file1, then the value from the array
       }
}' file2 file1
1:23
1:45
1:27
1:67
1:867
2:23
2:45
2:27
2:67
2:867
3:23
3:45
3:27
3:67
3:867
```

Or, perhaps with [GNU parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_parallel):

```
parallel echo {1}":"{2} :::: file1 :::: file2
1:23
1:45
1:27
1:67
1:867
2:23
2:45
2:27
2:67
2:867
3:23
3:45
3:27
3:67
3:867
```

If you have `<br/>` characters in your input, you can delete anything that isn't a number using:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{gsub("[^0-9]", "", $0); a[++n]=$0; next} {for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {gsub("[^0-9]", "", $0); print $0 ":" a[i]}}' file2 file1
```

Comment: not work result is different output

Comment: work just output like <br/> 1 <br/>:23<br/> not 1:23 but thanks for helping me

Comment: @VickyzSetiawan if you have `<br/>`s in your output then it's because you have `<br/>`s in your input - fix your input to not have `<br/>`s or ask a new question where your sample input has `<br/>`s.