# Formatting file using AWK because the file to large to edit

Tags: linux, awk, command

Formatting file using AWK, because the text is too large to be opened, and it crashes the editor when edited.

File a

```
1
:23
1
:27
1:67
```

To output:

```
1:23
1:27
1:67
```

How can I do the formatting using AWK to do the formatting like this output. Because a program like [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) and others can't open the file.

Comment: Please do add your tried code in your question to make it more clear, thank you.

Comment: you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76487005/awk-command-for-combine-two-file-with-separate-like-output

Comment: @VickyzSetiawan you're far more likely to get answers if you simply provide everything we need to understand your needs in your question rather than directing us to click around other locations to be able to piece them together.

Comment: It's also not obvious what your previous question has to do with your current one unless the current input is undesirable output from your previous answer, in which case fix THAT rather than adding yet another script to post-process it's output.

Comment: Some text editors ***can*** open very large files (they don't try to load the entire file into memory). Examples would be [UltraEdit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UltraEdit) (but very unfortunately they have changed to a ***subscription model***, and it is not at all clear if it stops working when the subscription runs out) and [Vim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
1
:23
1
:27
1:67
```

then

```
awk '{ORS=/:/?"\n":"";print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
1:23
1:27
1:67
```

Explanation: I set output-row-separator (`ORS`) to newline if it contains `:` and empty line otherwise, then `print` line, therefore all lines which do not have `:` before line with `:` and line with `:` will be concatenated.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Answer (score 0):

This works if there's only a lone **number** followed by a **:number** on the next line or a complete **number:number** (according to the given example)

```
% awk '/^:[[:digit:]]+/{print beg$1; beg = ""}
       /^[[:digit:]]+$/{beg = $1}
       /[[:digit:]]+:[[:digit:]]+/{print}' file
1:23
1:27
1:67
```

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '/:/{print p $0; p=""; next} {p=$1}' file
1:23
1:27
1:67
```